# Download File issue, CarrierWave upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, download, carrierwave

Thus far I have successfully set up CarrierWave so that it can upload many files including .pdf, .mp3, .wav, .mp4, and .mov.  Awesome that's a pretty good success for me.

What I am trying to do now is to display those Uploads.  On that display, I would like two links, one to download the uploaded file and the other to view the uploaded file.  Currently, viewing the uploaded files works when I was attempting to create a way for the user to download the file.

Currently, here is the code that allows a user to view/listen/watch the uploaded file:

```
<% @user.uploads.each do |upload| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to upload.name, upload.attachment_url.to_s %></td>
    <td class="right_align"><%= upload.to_a_date %></td>
    <td class="right_align"><%#= upload.file_size %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Clicking on the link above allows a user to view the upload.  How would I allow a user to download the same content?  This gives me the correct path, but when I click on the link it views the file rather than downloads it.

I have also tried to do this in html5 with the following code:

```
<a href="#{upload.attachment_url.to_s}" download>Download</a>
```

This doesn't download the correct file.

Comment: This is a server setting issue and not Ruby/Rails thing, however I am unable to tell you how to do it. What server are you using?

Comment: This is just locally right now on localhost.

Comment: Try deploying it on heroku and check if the problem persists. I think it will be gone.

Comment: I know this is an old post.  but do you have a github? I am trying to figure out how to allow mov's to be uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Create separate action for this and use Rails [`send_file`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) method:

```
def download_file
  upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
  send_file upload.attachment.url
end
```

Comment: Is this a controller action or a method.